# Comparison for something that's 251 million tons

Tags: essay, paper

I'm sorry this isn't directly about writing but I don't know where I'd for this kind of question. I'm writing a paper and I'm trying to come up with a comparison that can tell my audience, to give them a better idea of how much 251 million tons of trash is. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Compare it to something pwople are familiar with. If you want to give them an idea of the weight, 251 tons are about 251 cars. Depending on which aspect of the trash you are interested in (volume, energy used to produce it, energy gained by burning it, time until decomposition, etc.), find a comparative measure that people know from their everyday lives (baseball fields, households, etc.). If you update your question to explain which aspect your argument is about, I might have a more concrete idea.

Comment: @what In addition to the familiarity factor (which *is* important), at such less familiar scales giving a sense of magnitude (whether small or large) is also important. Comparing to mountain masses is popular for large masses, but using the car reference one might compare to the mass of registered cars in the U.S. (For a light essay targeting a science-literate audience, I would be tempted to write "about 25 teaspoonfuls of neutron star matter", but that is more playful than informative.)

Comment: Incidentally using "more than" or "about/almost N times more than" rather than "about" increases the sense of magnitude. (Similarly, "less than" or "about/not even an Nth the [dimensionality: mass, size, length, duration, etc.] of" can increase the sense of tininess.)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because, as you said, it's not actually a question about writing.  I'm sorry I don't know where to suggest you ask instead.

Answer (score 2):

Comparing to multiple smaller things is not nearly as evocative. You'd be hard-pressed to find an object of similar size, but we can always imagine one.

100 x 100 x 100 meters block of water is a million ton.

800 x 800 x 400 meters of water will be 256mln tons. Trash will occupy more as it's less dense. How much more? You're the expert.

Best if you can use an illustration.

Open Google Maps and find a location that is familiar to your audience. I picked the center of my city, the "old town" filled with antique buildings and relics of architecture.

Search area which is 800x800 or somehow a round multilple/divisor of that. I picked an 800x800 square, using Google Maps measure tool:

[image]

Find an aerial photo of that area, then find landmarks at the corners of your area. Draw the square in the respective perspective.

Extend the square by as much as the height would be, 400m is roughly half the side of the square. Make a cube. Adjust transparency and...

[image]

"It could cover the whole Old Town of Cracow with half a kilometer layer."

Let's pick a different location. Central Park in New York is about 800m wide, 4km long. So, divide the 400m height by 5. 80 meters layer, a tenth of the width...

[image]

"It would fill the Central Park area with a layer reaching over the tops of all but the highest of skyscrapers neighboring with it."

Adjust the volume for density, construct a cube of that volume at a familiar place, describe that cube.

Answer (score 1):

Try http://wolframalpha.com
That is the kind of searches the Computational Knowledge Engine answers.
Specifically this link: [http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=9.3%C3%9710^11+pounds&lk=1](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=9.3%C3%9710%5E11%20pounds&lk=1)
(shows the weight of all humans on earth, etc.)

I put in "251 million tons" and searched at WolframAlpha and got that answer.

**WolframAlpha Definition (from the site)**

> a fundamentally new way to get knowledge and answers— not by searching
>   the web, but by doing dynamic computations based on a vast collection
>   of built-in data, algorithms, and methods.